# drawImage, AnimationTimerの挙動がおかしい

Tags: java, javafx

いくつか問題があります。

n回に１回描画すると経過時間が(n-1)/nになる。60フレーム中２回なら0.5秒、３回なら0.66秒という感じ。
CPU使用率が徐々に上昇する。最初は１０％未満で、８０％程度まで確認。
毎フレーム描画すると非表示状態でタイマーの間隔が異常に短くなる。

こちらの環境はLubuntu15.04です。

コードは以下です。

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    int frame;
    long last;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(640, 480);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(32, 32);

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if (frame % 3 == 0) {
                    gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                }
                if (frame % 60 == 0) {
                    primaryStage.setTitle("" + (now - last) / 1_000_000_000.0);
                    last = now;
                }
                frame++;
            }
        }.start();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

java1.8.0_102でも同じ結果となりました。
WindowsXP,7で実行したところCPU使用率の上昇は見られませんでした。
Windows7の方にLubuntuを入れてやってみたら上昇しましたので、OS側の問題ということでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

【こちらWindows10、コード実行時のCPU使用率概ね5%以内です。javaのverは1.8.0_102です。
タイトルバーに表示される間隔は0.63～0.64です。】

非表示に間隔が短くなるのはimageの絵画がされていないだけなので、それは仕様かもしれません。
CPU使用率が異常なのはjavaを更新すれば治るかもしれません。

【コードの修正は必要ないと判断しました。】

Comment: 皆さんはどうですか。@straycat さん、いるようであれば返事をお願いします。